# SQL error 42P01 when using jsonb_to_recordset function

Tags: sql, jsonb, greenplum

I'm trying to display the contents of the jsonb column using the `jsonb_to_recordset` function:

```
SELECT id, city
FROM jsonb_to_recordset("sometable".data) AS t(id int4, city varchar)
```

But  get the following error

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "sometable"
```

The function itself works when I substitute the values manually. Сan't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it as a `FROM...JOIN`:

```
-- inner join
SELECT t.id, t.city
FROM sometable
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(sometable.data) AS t(id int4, city varchar)

-- outer join, include rows where jsonb is null
SELECT t.id, t.city
FROM sometable
LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(sometable.data) AS t(id int4, city varchar) ON true
```